# Passing additional parameters to MapStruct mapper

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

Haven't figured out how to pass in additional arguments or an alternative.

Currently I'm mapping an Order and OrderLines. Both objects are different and need @mappings. Example I have an Order and OrderRequest object both are different and need @Mappings annotation to map the values, same with OrderLines.

I've created the following mappers

- OrderMapper (uses = OrderLineMappers.class)
- OrderLineMappers (uses = OrderLineMapper.class)
- OrderLineMapper

So my issue is the OrderLine needs the OrderId from the Order object. However in the OrderLineMapper it's passing in the OrderLine and not the Order. How can I send the OrderId to the OrderLineMapper? Currently I have the OrderMapper doing an @AfterMapper, looping through the orderLines and populating with the OrderId.

Any help would be great.

Class OrderMapper

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",  uses = {OrderLineMappers.class})
public abstract class OrderMapper {

@AfterMapping
protected void orderRequestFromOrder( Order order, @MappingTarget 
OrderRequest orderRequest ) {

    //Wanting to do this at the OrderLineMapper class and not here
    String orderId = order.getId();
    List<OrderLineRequest> lines = orderRequest.getOrderLines();
    List<OrderLineRequest> updatedLines = new ArrayList<>();
    for (OrderLineRequest line : lines) {
        line.setOrderId(orderId);
        updatedLines.add(line);
    }
    orderRequest.setOrderLines(updatedLines);
}

@Mappings({
    @Mapping( source = "orderId", target = "id" ),
    @Mapping( source = "orderNumber", target = "order_number" ),
    @Mapping( source = "orderLines", target = "orderLines")
})
public abstract Order orderRequestToOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest);
```

Class OrderLineMappers

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",  uses = {OrderLineMapper.class})
public interface OrderLineMappers {

    List<OrderLine> orderLines(List<OrderLineRequest> orderLineRequest);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    List<OrderLineRequest> orderLineRequests(List<OrderLine> orderLine); 

}
```

Class OrderLineMapper

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class OrderLineMapper {
    @Mappings({
        @Mapping( target = "orderId", source = "orderLineId" ),
        @Mapping( target = "order_line_number", source = "orderLineNumber")

    })
    public abstract OrderLine orderLineRequestToOrderLine(OrderLineRequest orderLineRequest);
}
```

Again just trying to pass in the OrderId to the OrderLineMapper. Not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't really do this. What you can do instead is to use the `@Context` and perform your logic in it. You can have `@AfterMapping` and `@BeforeMapping` in your context where you can store the `Order` id and use that during its execution

e.g.

```java
public class OrderMappingContext {

    protected String currentOrderId;

    @BeforeMapping
    public void startMappingOrder(@MappingTarget Order order, OrderRequest request) {
        this.currentOrderId = request.getId();
    }

    @AfterMapping
    public void finishOrderMapping(@MappingTarget Order order) {
        this.currentOrderId = null;
    }

    @AfterMapping
    public void afterOrderLineMapping(@MappingTarget OrderLine orderLine) {
        orderLine.setOrderId(this.currentOrderId);
    }
}
```

Your mappers will then look like:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",  uses = {OrderLineMappers.class})
public abstract class OrderMapper {



    @Mapping( source = "orderId", target = "id" ),
    @Mapping( source = "orderNumber", target = "order_number" ),
    @Mapping( source = "orderLines", target = "orderLines")
    public abstract Order orderRequestToOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest, @Context OrderMappingContext context);
```

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",  uses = {OrderLineMapper.class})
public interface OrderLineMappers {

    List<OrderLine> orderLines(List<OrderLineRequest> orderLineRequest, @Context OrderMappingContext context);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    List<OrderLineRequest> orderLineRequests(List<OrderLine> orderLine); 

}
```

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class OrderLineMapper {

    @Mapping( target = "orderId", source = "orderLineId" ),
    @Mapping( target = "order_line_number", source = "orderLineNumber")
    public abstract OrderLine orderLineRequestToOrderLine(OrderLineRequest orderLineRequest, @Context OrderMappingContext context);
}
```

On the invocation side you will do something like

```
orderMapper.orderRequestToOrder(request, new OrderMappingContext());
```

Comment: An example would be really useful

Comment: I've added an example that showcases the idea

Answer (score 0):

I didnt even have to use context. I could simply pass the additional parameter and the mapper recognises it in the build.

```
    NotMORV2Entity toNotMorV2Entity(ReEntity reEntity, int glAccountTypeId);
```

Please also see [this](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct-multiple-source-objects) to understand more.