# Additional parameter in mapstruct mapper

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have Car:

- id
- brand
- model
- owner

And CarDTO:

- id
- brand
- model

In my service class I'm passing additional parameter "owner" and I need to convert the list.

Is it possible to add "owner" to Mapper?

If yes then I suppose it should be something similar to this (not working).

```
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {

@Mapping(target = "owner", source = "owner")
List<Car> mapCars(List<CarDTO> cars, String owner);
}
```

Comment: You can try using an expression: `@Mapping(target = "owner", expression = "java(owner)")`.

Comment: Hmm... This was the only solution that worked for me...

Comment: For Kotlin this way it works,     @Mappings(
        Mapping(target = "stockItemId",expression = "java(stockItemToMap)"),
        )
    fun convertFromResponseToModel(
        stockMappingPatchRequest: StockMappingPatchRequest,
        @Context stockItemToMap: StockItem,
    ): StockMapping

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74453567/10231374), you can use `@Context`.

Firstly, add a single object mapping method:

```java
@Maping(target = "owner", source = "owner")
Car mapCar(CarDTO car, String owner);
```

Then define a method for mapping a list of objects with `@Context`:

```java
List<Car> mapCars(List<CarDTO> cars, @Context String owner);
```

> Since `@Context` parameters are not meant to be used as source
> parameters, a proxy method should be added to point MapStruct to the
> right single object mapping method to make it work.

In the end, add the proxy method:

```java
default Car mapContext(CarDTO car, @Context String owner) {
    return mapCar(car, owner);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a build error java: No property named "owner" exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "yyy"? mapstruct 1.5.3.Final Do you possibly know what is causing that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You could try the `@Context` annotation before "owner"

I would suggest something like this:

```
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {

@Maping(target = "owner", source = "owner")
Car mapCar(CarDTO car, @Context String owner);

@Maping(target = "owner", source = "owner")
List<Car> mapAllCars(List<CarDTO> cars, @Context String owner);

@AfterMapping
default void afterMapping(@MappingTarget Car target, @Context String owner) {
    target.setOwner(owner);
}
```

there are multiple ways to approache your problem. You could also have a look at [Passing additional parameters to MapStruct mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50517750/passing-additional-parameters-to-mapstruct-mapper)

Answer (score 0):

I didnt even have to use context. I could simply pass the additional parameter and the mapper recognises it in the build.

```
    NotMORV2Entity toNotMorV2Entity(ReEntity reEntity, int glAccountTypeId);
```

Please also see [this](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct-multiple-source-objects) to understand more.